# Add search-function to RecyclerListview react Native

Tags: react-native, searchbar, recyclerlistview

I want to add a search/filter functionality to my RecyclerListView so that I can search items by typing the name inside a searchbar on top. I'm using this library: https://github.com/Flipkart/recyclerlistview

When the searchbar is empty, all items should be shown.

I tried looking at the library-documentation to see what they say on searching inside RecyclerListView, but no cigar.
Also, I found the [React Native Search Filter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-search-filter) package but have no idea how to implement this into a RecyclerListView.

Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, Profile, TextInput, Dimensions } from "react-native";
import { Profiler } from "react/cjs/react.production.min";
import { AudioContext } from "../context/AudioProvider";
import * as MediaLibrary from "expo-media-library";
import Screen from "../components/Screen";
import { DataProvider, LayoutProvider } from "recyclerlistview";
import { RecyclerListView } from "recyclerlistview";
import AudioListItem from "../components/AudioListItem";
import OptionModal from "../components/OptionModal";
import { Audio } from "expo-av";
import {
  play,
  pause,
  resume,
  playNext,
  updatePitch,
  selectAudio,
  AddToQueue,
} from "../misc/AudioController";
import { goBack } from "./PlayListDetail";
import { storeAudioForNextOpening } from "../misc/helper";
//import { PlayRate } from "./Settings";
import { hidePlayList } from "./Playlist";
import "./Settings";

//console.log(global.PlayRate);

export class AudioList extends Component {
  
  static contextType = AudioContext;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { optionModalVisible: false };
    this.currentItem = {};
  }

  dataProvider = new DataProvider((r1, r2) => {
    return r1 !== r2;
  });


  layoutProvider = new LayoutProvider(
    (i) => "audio",
    (type, dim) => {
      dim.width = Dimensions.get("window").width;
      dim.height = 63;
    }
  );

  // onPlaybackStatusUpdate = async (playbackStatus) => {
  //   console.log("hier");
  //   if (playbackStatus.isLoaded && playbackStatus.isPlaying) {
  //     this.context.updateState(this.context, {
  //       playbackPosition: playbackStatus.positionMillis,
  //       playbackDuration: playbackStatus.durationMillis,
  //     });
  //   }
  //
  //   if (playbackStatus.didJustFinish) {
  //      const nextAudioIndex = this.context.currentAudioIndex + 1;
  //     if (nextAudioIndex >= this.context.totalAudioCount) {
  //        this.context.playbackObj.unloadAsync();
  //        return this.context.updateState(this.context, {
  //          soundObj: null,
  //          currentAudio: this.context.audioFiles[0],
  //          isPlaying: false,
  //          currentAudioIndex: 0,
  //          playbackPosition: null,
  //          playbackDuration: null,
  //        });
  //      }
  //      const audio = this.context.audioFiles[nextAudioIndex];
  //      const status = await playNext(this.context.playbackObj, audio.uri);
  //      this.context.updateState(this.context, {
  //        soundObj: status,
  //        currentAudio: audio,
  //       isPlaying: true,
  //        currentAudioIndex: nextAudioIndex,
  //      });
  //    }
  //  };

  handleAudioPress = async (audio) => {
      await selectAudio(audio,this.context);
  };

  componentDidMount() {
   this.context.loadPreviousAudio()
   }

  rowRenderer = (type, item, index, extendedState) => {
    return (
      <AudioListItem
        title={item.filename}
        isPlaying={extendedState.isPlaying}
        activeListItem={this.context.currentAudioIndex === index}
        duration={item.duration}
        onAudioPress={() => this.handleAudioPress(item)}
        onOptionPress={() => {
          this.currentItem = item;
          this.setState({ ...this.state, optionModalVisible: true });
        }}
      />
    );
  };

  navigateToPlaylist = () => {
    
      //
      console.log("navigate");
      this.context.updateState(this.context, {
      addToPlayList: this.currentItem,
      });
      this.props.navigation.navigate("Playlist");
      }

  // addToQueue = () => {
    
  // }



  render() {
    if(global.Hz === undefined){
      global.Hz = 440
    }
    return (
      <>
      <View style = {styles.viewStyle}>
        <Text style = {{fontWeight: 'bold',fontSize: 24, }}>{global.Hz} Hz mode</Text>
      </View>
      
      <AudioContext.Consumer>
        {({ dataProvider, isPlaying }) => {
          if(!dataProvider._data.length) return null;
          return (
            <View style={{ minHeight: 1, minWidth: 1, flex: 1 }}>
              {dataProvider && dataProvider.getSize() > 0 && (
                <RecyclerListView
                  dataProvider={dataProvider}
                  layoutProvider={this.layoutProvider}
                  rowRenderer={this.rowRenderer}
                  extendedState={{ isPlaying }}
                />
              )}
              <OptionModal
               // onPlayPress={() => console.log("play")}
               // onPlaylistPress={() => {
               //   this.context.updateState(this.context, {
               //     addToPlayList: this.currentItem,
               //   });
               //   this.props.navigation.navigate("Playlist");
               // }}
                options ={[{title: 'Add to playlist',onPress: this.navigateToPlaylist } /* , {title: 'Add to qeue', onPress: console.log("yes")}*/]}
                currentItem={this.currentItem}
                onClose={() =>
                  this.setState({ ...this.state, optionModalVisible: false })
                }
                visible={this.state.optionModalVisible}
              />
            </View>
          );
        }}
      </AudioContext.Consumer>
      </>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  viewStyle: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingLeft: 20,
    paddingBottom: 10
  }
});

export default AudioList;
```

Comment: Please indicate the code with proper language when using triple-backticks, because otherwise it's hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, replace RecyclerListView with [@shopify/flashlist](https://shopify.github.io/flash-list/). It uses the same recyclerListView under the hood but offers the familiar Flatlist props. Then follow one of the [many available guides](https://www.crowdbotics.com/blog/add-search-bar-flatlist-react-native-apps) on building a search bar for a flatlist.The process should be mostly the same since flatlist and flashlist share most of the same props.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply. However, I'm wondering what kind of list I should pass into the data-prop. In my case it must be the list of all audiofiles stored on the device, but I'm not sure as to how to obtain this list and pass it into the 'data-prop'. The code I'm currently using to obtain a list of all audioFiles is here: (I'm using a dataProvider to pass the data to the recyclerlistView):

````
import {Text, View, Alert } from 'react-native'
import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library';
import { DataProvider } from 'recyclerlistview';
import {Audio} from 'expo-av';
import { play, pause, resume, playNext, updatePitch } from "../misc/AudioController";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

export const AudioContext = createContext();
export class AudioProvider extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      audioFiles: [],
      playList: [],
      addToPlayList: null,
      permissionError: false,
      dataProvider: new DataProvider((r1, r2) => r1 !== r2),
      playbackObj: null,
      soundObj: null,
      currentAudio: {},
      isPlaying: false,
      isPlayListRunning: false,
      activePlayList: [],
      currentAudioIndex: null,
      playbackPosition: null,
      playbackDuration: null,
      rate: 3,
    };
    this.totalAudioCount = 0;
  }

  permissionAlert = () => {
    Alert.alert("Permission Required", "This app needs to read audio files", [
      { text: "I am ready", onPress: () => this.getPermission() },
      {
        text: "cancel",
        onPress: () => this.permissionAlert(),
      },
    ]);
  };

  getAudioFiles = async () => {
    const { dataProvider, audioFiles } = this.state;
    let media = await MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync({
      mediaType: "audio",
    });
    media = await MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync({
      mediaType: "audio",
      first: media.totalCount,
    });
    this.totalAudioCount = media.totalCount;

    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      dataProvider: dataProvider.cloneWithRows([
        ...audioFiles,
        ...media.assets,
      ]),
      audioFiles: [...audioFiles, ...media.assets],
    });
  };

  loadPreviousAudio = async () => {
    let previousAudio = await AsyncStorage.getItem("previousAudio");
    let currentAudio;
    let currentAudioIndex;

    if (previousAudio === null) {
      currentAudio = this.state.audioFiles[0];
      currentAudioIndex = 0;
    } else {
      previousAudio = JSON.parse(previousAudio);
      currentAudio = previousAudio.audio;
      currentAudioIndex = previousAudio.index;
    }
    this.setState({ ...this.state, currentAudio, currentAudioIndex });
  };

  getPermission = async () => {
    //    {
    //    "canAskAgain": true,
    //    "expires": "never",
    //    "granted": false,
    //    "status": "undetermined",
    //    }
    const permission = await MediaLibrary.getPermissionsAsync();
    if (permission.granted) {
      this.getAudioFiles();
    }
    if (!permission.canAskAgain && !permission.granted) {
      this.setState({ ...this.state, permissionError: true });
    }

    if (!permission.granted && permission.canAskAgain) {
      const { status, canAskAgain } =
        await MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync();
      if (status === "denied" && canAskAgain) {
        this.permissionAlert();
      }

      if (status === "granted") {
        this.getAudioFiles();
      }

      if (status === "denied" && !canAskAgain) {
        this.setState({ ...this.state, permissionError: true });
      }
    }
  };

  onPlaybackStatusUpdate = async (playbackStatus) => {
    //console.log(global.PlayRate);
    if (playbackStatus.isLoaded && playbackStatus.isPlaying) {
      this.updateState(this, {
        playbackPosition: playbackStatus.positionMillis,
        playbackDuration: playbackStatus.durationMillis,
      });
    }

    if(playbackStatus.isLoaded && !playbackStatus.isPlaying){
      storeAudioForNextOpening(this.state.currentAudio, 
        this.state.currentAudioIndex, playbackStatus.positionMillis)
    }

    if (playbackStatus.didJustFinish) {
      if(this.state.isPlayListRunning) {
        let audio;
        const indexOnPlayList = this.state.activePlayList.audios.findIndex(({id}) => id === this.state.currentAudio.id )
        const nextIndex = indexOnPlayList + 1;
        audio = this.state.activePlayList.audios[nextIndex];

        if(!audio) audio = this.state.activePlayList.audios[0];

        const indexOnAllList = this.state.audioFiles.findIndex(({id}) => id === audio.id)

        const status = await playNext(this.state.playbackObj, audio.uri)
        return this.updateState(this, {soundObj: status,
            isPlaying: true,
            currentAudio: audio,
            currentAudioIndex: indexOnAllList,
          });

      }
      const nextAudioIndex = this.state.currentAudioIndex + 1;
      if (nextAudioIndex >= this.totalAudioCount) {
        this.state.playbackObj.unloadAsync();
        this.updateState(this, {
          soundObj: null,
          currentAudio: this.state.audioFiles[0],
          isPlaying: false,
          currentAudioIndex: 0,
          playbackPosition: null,
          playbackDuration: null,
        });
        return await storeAudioForNextOpening(
          this.state.audioFiles[0],
          0
        );
      }

      //otherwise, select the next audio
      const audio = this.state.audioFiles[nextAudioIndex];

      const status = await playNext(this.state.playbackObj, audio.uri);
      this.updateState(this, {
        soundObj: status,
        currentAudio: audio,
        isPlaying: true,
        currentAudioIndex: nextAudioIndex,
      });
      await storeAudioForNextOpening(audio, nextAudioIndex);
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getPermission();
    if (this.state.playbackObj === null) {
      this.setState({ ...this.state, playbackObj: new Audio.Sound() });
    }
  }

  updateState = (prevState, newState = {}) => {
    this.setState({ ...prevState, ...newState });
  };

  render() {
    const {
      audioFiles,
      dataProvider,
      playList,
      addToPlayList,
      permissionError,
      playbackObj,
      soundObj,
      currentAudio,
      isPlaying,
      currentAudioIndex,
      playbackPosition,
      playbackDuration,
      rate,
      isPlayListRunning,
      activePlayList,
    } = this.state;
    if (permissionError)
      return (
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
          }}
        >
          <Text>It looks like you haven't accepted the permission</Text>
        </View>
      );
    return (
      <AudioContext.Provider
        value={{
          audioFiles,
          dataProvider,
          playList,
          addToPlayList,
          playbackObj,
          soundObj,
          currentAudio,
          isPlaying,
          currentAudioIndex,
          totalAudioCount: this.totalAudioCount,
          playbackPosition,
          playbackDuration,
          isPlayListRunning,
          activePlayList,
          rate,
          updateState: this.updateState,
          loadPreviousAudio: this.loadPreviousAudio,
          onPlaybackStatusUpdate: this.onPlaybackStatusUpdate,
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </AudioContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}


import {Component} from 'react';
import { storeAudioForNextOpening } from '../misc/helper';

export default AudioProvider;```
````

Comment: Please do not post replies as answers. Reply in comments or use separate session chats, that can be linked to.

Do post your answer to your question if no other answer matches it once you figured it out or got a proper reply in the comments / separate chat.